# The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'Employee' is not instantiable

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

My error:

> The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'Employee' is not instantiable and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type

I'm trying to use migration in EF Core. I'm using a Code-First approach.

I have one abstract class named `Employee` which has properties like `Id`, `Name`, `UserId`.

My requirement is to specify whether an `Employee` is `Contract` or `Permanent`.

My code is as follows:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

My concrete class:

```
public class Contract : Employee
{
    // Left empty because I don't want to add any other columns
}

public class Permanent : Employee
{
    // Left empty because I don't want to add any other columns
}
```

and my DbContext:

```
public class CoreDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Contract>();
        builder.Entity<Permanent>();
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);        
    }
}
```

Correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define a mapping of class `Employee` to a table, like this:

```
builder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
```

This uses the Table Per Class Hierarchy/Single Table Hierarchy mapping model, which uses a column as the discriminator between the different types that are stored on the same table.

Comment: Thanks a lot i didn't get that error now. Will it create discriminator column in my employee table automatically ?

Comment: It should, yes, if you are using code first to create the database for you.

Comment: yes i'm using code first . but i got error as "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Invalid column name 'Discriminator''" when i tried to load that page

Answer (score -2):

Remove "abstract" from class definition. I don't know why it is like that.